# What is the distance scale from real world to game?

Tags: assassins-creed-odyssey

I love playing *Assassin’s Creed: Odyssey* but it is ridiculous to think we can, in 10 minutes, jog across islands that housed entire ancient civilizations.

So what is the game distance scale to real world?

Answer (score 6):

I used Kephallonia to measure the game distance.

[image: Kephallonia game map zoomed in]

From one tip to the other is 1298 meters.

I used Apple Maps to route a similar distance on Cephalonia (as it is now spelled, I guess).

[image: Apple Map screen shot of Cephalonia]

Apple Maps lists the distance as 41 miles.

41 miles is 65.983 kilometers. That is 65983 meters.

1298 / 65983 = 0.01967

65983 / 1298 = 50.8

So the scale of game world to real word is 1:50. If your character walks 100 meters then you yourself would have to walk 5 km.

To put it another way, the developers shrunk the real world to 2% of its original size.